# How to mapping an object from 2 array in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, mapping

I have 2 array. I would like to mapping an object of array, then return the object.

```
$FirstArray = @("AB", "AC", "DA", "ES")
$SecondArray = @("AB", "AC","ES", "FL", "PA")
```

I want to mapping the first array, which object is not exist in the second array, then return the object.

Anyone can help me please thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are wanting to find and output any object that exists in $FirstArray but does not exist in $SecondArray.

One easy approach is to use a `where` clause with the `-notin` operator.

```
$FirstArray = @("AB", "AC", "DA", "ES")
$SecondArray = @("AB", "AC","ES", "FL", "PA")

$FirstArray.Where({$_ -notin $SecondArray})

DA
```

Conversely, you could use -notcontains like this.

```
$FirstArray.Where({$SecondArray -notcontains $_})

DA
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks a lot. That's what I need. Appreciated. @Dough